# What it the b2XForm equivalent in Box2D for AS3 v2.1a?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, box2d

I am following this tutorial on creating a top-down car using Box2D:
Link: [Two ways to make Box2D cars](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars/)

Everything is fine until I reach the `killOrthogonalVelocity` function, line 152.
This code uses `b2XForm` which is not available in the current version of Box2D.

What is the equivalent of it in v2.1a? Or the work around is there isn't?

I've tried searching for the solution online and even emailed the host 2-3 days ago to no avail...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I've solved it.

`b2XForm` has been renamed to `b2Tranform` in v2.1a.

All functions and whatnot are the same...